# Connect Qt with VS project

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2012

I have a c++ console project with all the models, and program logic.

I would like to create an interface that will enable user interaction.

Is there an easy way to import all my classes and code to be used in the Qt project? Or should I download the Qt plugin for VS?

EDIT:

I am targeting Qt 5.2, and VS 2012.

Maybe my question isn't to clear. I'd rather leave the console project alone, and just use the models and logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an easy way to import all my classes and code to be used in the Qt project? Or should I download the Qt plugin for VS?

I believe, the plugin would make your life somewhat simpler. Please note that they do not work with the free express edition though, so if you can only use that, it is not your piece of cake.

You can download the Qt 4 add-in from [here](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/vsaddin/qt-vs-addin-1.1.11-opensource.exe), and the Qt 5 add-in from [here](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/vsaddin/qt-vs-addin-1.2.2-opensource.exe).

You can leave the console project as is, and you can link against the common functionality in your Qt frontend by selecting the desired library path and name of your library covering the models and the business logic.